# Removing a member id, Second redirect

Tags: php

So I'm trying to get another redirect when you go and delete a member. This is what currently is happening

`onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker het zeker om dit te verwijderen?')" href="?delete=<?php echo $row['Ledens_ID']; ?>`

As soon as i press "Ready" on my pop-up, it gives me a 500 error because the "admin/leden?delete=115" isn't a page.

My question is can i add another redirect so it will go back to my site or another button so it doesn't have to leave my site

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend using AJAX and jQuery

E.g.

```
<button onclick=“del_user(this)” data-user-id=“<?php echo $row['Ledens_ID']; ?>”>Delete</button>

<script>
    function del_user(button) {
        var user_id = $(button).data(“user-id”);

        //Ajax call

        //on success, refresh the page, or don’t redirect at all and just remove the user row, e.g.
        $(“#user_row” + user_id).remove();
 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is giving me 2 SyntaxErrors https://imgur.com/a/m2ykGt3

Comment: the issue you are getting is from the “ characters, you’ll need to replace them with your own. I’m on my phone so the character is different to what “ would be on your keyboard / computer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a error 500 redirect in my .htacces

`ErrorDocument 500 http://crm.adcdefg.nl/admin`

Comment: Ideally you’d want to look for a fix for the error rather than just hiding the error.